# Producing plots with R Markdown when "knitting" to html

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, markdown, knitr

**UPDATE: I solved this problem with something silly. I had to include a line space prior to the code chunks with the plots, then it worked as I'd hoped. Thank you for your time with this question.**

I have a markdown document that is working perfectly when I "knit" to Word or pdf. However, when I "knit" to html none of the plots appear. There are similar questions on stack overflow, but nothing that I could find that duplicates the issue

This is the instruction I am trying to use in the code chunk (it doesn't work):

```
{r, emotional circumplex, fig.align = "center", echo=FALSE}
```

However, when I set the instruction to this, I get the plot:

```
{r, emotional circumplex, fig.align = "center", echo=TRUE}
```

The problem is, I don't want to produce the code in the html document, just the plot.

I tried the "stock" markdown example, presented below, but that didn't appear in an html document either:

````
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

This is the YAML info:

```
---
title: "HTML TEST"
author: "Pete Miksza"
date: "12/12/2017"
output: html_document
---
```

It's not reproducible, but here's the code chunk for my actual plot:

````
```{r, emotional circumplex, fig.align = "center", echo=FALSE}
# Emotional Circumplex
ggplot(charlie_brown_dat, aes(x = scale(energy), y = scale(valence))) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = Tempo, shape = PopularitySplit), color = "darkgreen") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "red") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "red") +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = track_name), size = 1.7, point.padding = .75) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-2.5, 2.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-2.5, 2.5)) +
  labs(title = "Where do the Tracks Sit on an Emotion Circumplex?", 
       x = "\nValence \n(- negative to + positive)", y = "\nArousal \n(- low energy to + high energy)") +  
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 9, face = "italic"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 9, face = "italic"),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 8),
        legend.key.size =  unit(.05, "in"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 6.5),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "lightgray"))
```
````

I receive no warning messages, but this is included in the markdown output in my console:

```
/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS Music_from_a_Charlie_Brown_Christmas.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output Music_from_a_Charlie_Brown_Christmas.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template /Users/pmiksza/Library/R/3.4/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable 'theme:bootstrap' --include-in-header /var/folders/pw/1hpqdrzn5853ys3whns5mg34vh62tx/T//RtmpOt8rhU/rmarkdown-str1dc15577eea.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'
```

Comment: The plot not showing in the stock example is odd. Do you see any warnings or errors in the log when creating the stock example (in the RMarkdown tab of the console)?

Comment: Also I think chunk names should occur before the first comma and should not contain spaces, like `{r emotional_circumplex, fig.align = "center", echo=FALSE}`. Not sure if that will fix anything though.

Comment: What errors are showing in the knitr output log? What's in the YAML header? What other knitr settings are being set that you aren't showing? Marius is correct in that it's not a gd idea to use spaces in the names. What OS are you on? etc. Def more info is req'd.

Comment: Thanks for engaging on this question, I've edited my original question with responses to these comments.

Answer (score 2):

As a quick temporary fix it is possible to save your plots as *.jpg* files and then read the images into the RMarkdown file.

Here's an example:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(jpeg)

img <- readJPEG('cat.jpeg')

plot(1:2, type='n')
graphics::rasterImage(img,1,1,2,2)
```
````

[image]
This code chunk will produce the image without the code. Again not a permanent solution but if you have a deadline this might work.

Also, try to hash out some of the auxiliary code in your `ggplot` object (such as the `labs` and the `theme`) and knit the markdown, and see if anything changes

Comment: Thank you for this solution.